# multiset count method not working with class comparator

Tags: c++, stl, multiset

I have this struct

```cpp
struct C {
    int ID;
    int age;
    C(int ID, int age) : ID{ID}, age{age} {}
};
```

I use a comparator function for a multiset

```cpp
bool fncomp (const C& lhs, const C& rhs) {
    return lhs.age < rhs.age;
}

multiset<C, decltype(fncomp)*> ms{fncomp};
ms.emplace(1, 15);
...

// this works fine
ms.count(C(1, 15));
```

However if I use a class comparator, this is no longer working.

```cpp
struct classcomp {
    bool operator() (const C& lhs, const C& rhs) {
        return lhs.age < rhs.age;
    }
};

multiset<C, classcomp> ms;
ms.emplace(1, 15);
...

// error
// ms.count(C(1, 15));
```

Anything makes the two different?

Comment: What is the error? If this was a [mcve] I could copy/paste/compile it to see, but it isn't and I shouldn't have to.

Comment: bool operator() (const C& lhs, const C& rhs) *const* {

Comment: As a side note. That should work as long as you don't have two objects with the same age. I would use this comparison: `std::tie(lhs.age, lhs.ID) <
std::tie(rhs.age, rhs.ID);`

Comment: here's the example: https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3xvec6n74. think Marshall solved my problem - make the method const

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment above:

`multiset::count` is a const member function, which means that it operates on a `const multiset`. This includes the member variables of the multiset. The comparator is a member variable of the multiset.

Since your `classcomp::operator()` is not marked `const`, it can't be called on a const object, and so it fails to compile.

This works for the function pointer example, because it's the *pointer* that is const in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool operator() (const C& lhs, const C& rhs) const  {
    return lhs.age < rhs.age;
}
```

This would fix things to compile in [this link](https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3xvec6n74.) you provided, courtesy of @Marshall -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/71384594/10630957